How to change base of Bolt - Bolt Factory
I'm trying to design a model of a device that I will try to 3D print.
One core element of this device is, that it has a thread. Imagine a pen with a thread around it.
So I thought the Add-on BoltFactory will give me a good starting point.
But my challenge is, that I want my device to continue as a straight Cylinder at the base, about the size of the minor diameter of the screw. Basically a version of the shaft on the top, but at the base of the bolt.
But with the pitch value I chose, the base of the screw gets quite pointy. (Image 1)
I've had different ideas to solve it. But they all include either quite a lot of manual work or they make a messy mesh.
And assuming that I will have to tweak the bolt values after my first printed prototypes, I fear that it's gonna be very inefficient if I have to manually connect a cylinder to the bolt every time I tweak the settings. Like I did in image 2.
So does anybody have an Idea on how to achieve this efficiently/or in a non-destructive way?
Or is there a possibility we might get a feature in the Add-on for the base shape and size, like there is for the shaft?
Thanks for the help! :)

